# Different MD5 with as3corelib

Tags: actionscript-3, md5

I'm trying to md5 some file with *as3corelib*, but if I compare the as3 hash with a php one, I get different strings.

That's what I do:

```
_loader = new URLLoader();
_loader.load( new URLRequest( "image.jpg" ) );
_loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler );

private function completeHandler( event:Event ):void {
       var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray(); 
       data.writeUTFBytes( _loader.data );
       var hash:MD5Stream = new MD5Stream();
       trace(hash.complete(data));
}
```

I've already googled for this issue, finding this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581242/md5-hash-in-c-doesnt-match-md5-hash-in-action-script) where a similar thing is discussed (making an hash of a string).

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set the loader *dataFormat* property to *URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY* prior to the load() call:

```
_loader = new URLLoader();
_loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
_loader.load( new URLRequest( "image.jpg" ) );
_loader.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler );

private function completeHandler( event:Event ):void {
       var hash:MD5Stream = new MD5Stream();
       trace(hash.complete(_loader.data));
}
```

Then use directly the _loader.data variable since now it's a ByteArray