# Md5 Password in AS3

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, passwords, md5

I have a problem recreating a password that's hashed in C#. In an online project when a user do the registration process his password is save after passing for this function:

```
private static string ToMD5Hash(string inputString)
{
   using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
   {
      byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(inputString);
      byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(data);

      return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
   }
}
```

I'm working on an offline version that at some point will do a sync with the online version and I can't reproduce the same results on AS3 (Adobe Air). For example the password "1234" after passing to the C# code will be "DwN1hMmef9T0+MWVUPj1Bw==".

Can someone help me out?

My AS3 code is like this:

```
private function encode():void
{
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba.writeMultiByte("1234","unicode");
var str:String = MD5.hash(ba.toString());

var ba2:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
ba2.writeMultiByte(str.toString(),"unicode");

var encoder:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
encoder.encodeUTFBytes(ba2.toString());
    trace(encoder.toString());
}
```

When I do the `ba.writeMultiByte("1234","unicode");` I get exactly the same `ByteArray` as in the C# but when I do the `MD5.hash(ba.toString());` the new `ByteArray` is different.

Comment: What does your as3 function look like? What's the value you get out of it? It might be a character encoding problem, you are using `Encoding.Unicode`, which I believe is UTF16, and I would assume your as3 encoding is UTF8, but it's hard to say without seeing what you are doing.

Comment: Hi 32bitkid, i have added my as3 code, thanks in advance Alex

Comment: I think you've got way too many `toString()` calls in your actionscript version. I don't think it does what you think it's going to do. Especially when you pass to `ByteArray` to the md5 hasher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like it may be a bug in as3corelib's implementation of writing the bits to the `digest` `ByteArray`.

It seemingly writes them in [big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) format, rather than little endian. Or more specifically, it writes the bits as a collection of 4 integers rather than a collection of bytes, and in the process it mangles the byte order of the bits (which is why you are seeing different Base64 results -- the bytes are in a different order).

You can address this bug by adding on [line 184 of MD5.as](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/crypto/MD5.as#L184),  in as3corelib, insert the following one line of code:

```
digest.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
```

Also make sure you add an import at the top of the file for `import flash.utils.Endian`. I've created a public gist of the changes available [here](https://gist.github.com/2637849)

Then it should generate the same byte order as c#, and then it should Base64 encode the same way. I verified it using the following as3 function:

```
    private function encode():void 
    { 
        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        ba.endian = Endian.BIG_ENDIAN
        ba.writeMultiByte("1234","unicode");
        var str:String = MD5.hashBytes(ba);

        var encoder:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
        encoder.encodeBytes(MD5.digest);
        trace(encoder.toString()); // DwN1hMmef9T0+MWVUPj1Bw==
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?295966-MD5-in-AS3-0).

Be aware that the original download mentioned in that site has a few bugs, so that you have to use the corrected vesion that you can find in the same post.

If you're using AS3CoreLib, do it this way:

[Different MD5 with as3corelib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883688/different-md5-with-as3corelib).

Comment: Hi JotaBe, i already seen that post but without sucess i forgot to mention that i was trying to use the as3corelib, but none of the ways i can reproduce the same result. Thanks for your help any way.

Comment: Hi, i was checking everything again and my problem is when i do MD5.hash() in AS3 i just do myBytearray.toString() and the result is diferent from the one i get on the c#, everything is the same result. Thanks in advance